Advice on using Mediapipe Services from separate workers
I am using Face Landmarker + blendshapes,  and Gesture Recognizer at the same time, in the context of a complex Three.js-based application.
My development computer is a i7-14k and a nVidia RTX 4060Ti that should be up for the job.

the technique involves transferring a ImageBitmap with the current video frame to each worker - something that should be GPU accelerated and in any case should be quite efficient.

The issue:
I can observe very degraded performance on the Gesture Recognizer in the following situations:

Running a Worker with both face recognition + hand recognition called sequentially

Running two workers, one for face recognition and another for hand recognition. In this case, the vision_internal_wasm_*files would be duplicated in each worker (imported with importScripts)


Findings

Using only one worker for both services causes both to be degraded (obvious as I sent aggregated results at the end)
Separating each service in an independent worker

if both use Delegate "GPU", face landmarks are always snappy but Gesture Recognition is very degraded (jumps if hand is moved quickly and low fps)
Using delegate:"CPU" on the Gesture Recognizer  improves a lot, providing nearly realtime response and very little lag.



Questions

Is having separate workers per mediapipe service a sound approach?
Can mediapipe vision_**** cause contentions if included in several workers at the same time?

